# Can coverage.py be used to measure code coverage of specific file in a python Google App Engine app?

Tags: google-app-engine, coverage.py

I am currently working through the process of trying to measure code coverage for python files in a Python Google App Engine app. I'd like to run the dev server locally and then run my gaeunit tests and measure the coverage that they produce.

Is there a recommended way to measure coverage of python files in a GAE app when using GAEUnit rather than NOSE? Here is the commandline that I'm working towards.

> > coverage run --source=/Users/me/myapp /usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py myapp -p 8080

Then access localhost/tests and shutdown the dev_appserver after the tests are complete.

> > coverage html

Comment: Hi @Chris have you got any breakthrough in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following (from my app root) when running coverage.py with GAEUnit:

```
coverage run --source=./ /usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore --use_sqlite .
```

Comment: How would you recommend automating the process of start server, access /tests, stop server, run report. A python script, a bash file, some other approach?

Comment: @Chris, I setup a shell script called run_coverage.sh that runs the dev_server under coverage and initiates the tests.

Comment: Do you use ?format=plain? I ask because I frequently get different results from using format=plain but it seems that I will need to use format=plain in my CI setup.